# Add item to spinner after it has already been filled

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I create a spinner somewhere in my code and fill it in with values

```
val dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, some_list)

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
mySpinner?.adapter = dataAdapter
```

My Question is, How do I add more items to this spinner after I have applied the adapter in a completely different section of code in Kotlin? for example, after a server request

I understand you can access the adapter via

```
mySpinner?.adapter
```

But how do I add to it?

**EDIT.**
I Understand there is a solution in the following code

```
some_list.add("Apple");
dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

However this requires having access to 3 data items at a class or global level instead of just 1 (the spinner). I understand this may be the only way, it is just sub-optimal, thank you for your responses

Comment: 4th google entry .... https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-spinner-add-item-dynamically.html

Comment: The problem I have with that solution is that the ArrayAdapter is only accessible from within onCreate. it would mean that I would have to have the ArrayAdapter be accessible to the entire class to use it in another function which I am already doing with the spinner

Comment: declare `ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter myAdapter;`  outside the methods, asign it inside the method and use it whereever you want

Comment: @K.Dexter Professional coding dictates that variables should be declared at the function level as much as possible. But I appreciate your answer nonetheless as there seems to be no other solution

Comment: You only need access to the `ArrayAdapter`. And you can directly add items to an `ArrayAdapter` and then use `notifyDataSetChanged`- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#add(T)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new adapter with a the newest list and then assign it to the spinner , or you can create a custom adapter with your item list and then just add the new item to the list and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I was kind of hoping to avoid dragging the value of an array adapter around my code with the spinner. Something like arrayAdapter = mySpinner?.adapter. arrayAdapter.add("someValue"). mySpinner?.adapter = arrayAdapter
Would be more appropriate

Comment: you should avoid adapter reassigning, this is a costly operation, instead use add and remove operations.

Comment: @Daniel I agree with you. But all the solutions I have seen so far have meant that I need to have both the Spinner and the ArrayAdapter would need to be declared at a high enough level for everything that needs to access it to access it. It would be much cleaner to be able to just access the adapter from within the spinner by calling the spinner, but alas it seems android does not allow for it